# permalink error when calling get_absolute_url

Tags: python, django

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('threads_reply', [self.id])
    get_absolute_url = models.permalink(get_absolute_url)
```

I am migrating app from django 1.8 to django 2.2 and python 2.7 to python 3.6
I am getting error at that function, how can I change it correctly?
I tried multiple ways it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) method:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('threads_reply', args=[self.id])
```

Comment: i know but what about get_absolute_url  = models.permalink(get_absolute_url) as am calling from my html <a href="{{ thread.get_absolute_url }}" class="message-link">